# Bathroom - inline fan on gently sloped ceiling above shower

Tags: bathroom, ceiling-fan, ventilation, fans

I need to replace the current extractor fan in the bathroom of a ground floor flat and an inline fan was recommended as the most powerful (there is no windows in the bathroom and it's tiny so moisture is a problem). As the bathroom is under the stairs the ceiling above the shower is slightly sloped ~35° it would be possible to run the ducting behind this wall and then through an external wall immediately behind this in quick succession. Considering the shallow slope of the ceiling would this still be effective?

Comment: It's real hard to say without knowing why you're worried, or what you're proposing.  Maybe with another 1000 words, or a picture?

Comment: Is it going  where the old extractor was, or what?? More info. please.

Comment: Added a picture, the vent would be going in the sloped part of the wall behind the shower. Inline fan instructions seem to talk only about installation in the ceiling. If the vent was in the sloped portion of the wall would this still be effective? I need to reduce the humidity as much as possible to prevent mould/condensation